# NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

I have this audio element on my page :

```
 <audio id="splayer" controls="controls" class="audiocontrol" >
 <source src='{{ baseUrl}}storage/{{src}}' />
 </audio>

    start_audio()
    {  

      var player = <HTMLAudioElement> document.querySelector('#splayer');
      player.load();
      var promise = player.play();


      if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(_ => {
          
        }).catch(error => { console.log('error');
          console.log(error)
        });
      }
    }
```

This is working on chrome and firefox but getting this error on Safari :

> NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the
> platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied
> permission

There is a modal which loads at the initial page load and user clicks on allow button to give permission :

```
   <button class="btn micallowbtn" data-dismiss="modal">Allow</button>
```

This works on chrome but getting error on safari.

Any solution to resolve this issue on Safari

Comment: Is the button click calling the function start_audio() ?

Comment: @rodurico no start_audio function is not being called on button click

Comment: Safari blocks programatically triggered media, you need a user action. Try calling start_audio() upon a click event, it should work!

Comment: Nope, not working sadly!

Comment: @Kokodoko Any update on this ?

Comment: In your code, it doesn't look like the button calls the `start_audio()` function. I don't think you need to call `load()` manually, audio should load as soon as you set a source. If you want you can check the loading state with `canplay` and `readyState`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio